# why the following snippets always return an empty array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am pretty new to RoR.

I have two models:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
end
```

In the controller:

```
@a = A.find(params[:a_id] || params[:id])
@bs = @a.bs
```

I think I can always get `@a`, but `@a.bs` always returns []?

Answer (score 0):

Does the `a` record actually has some `bs` persisted? If not, then `@a.bs` should return an empty array.